# Accessory type for Cross Sign in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a table view and 2 custom cells inside it. I want to use a (X) symbol i.e. the cross symbol and the tick symbol. I know for tick we have UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark but what to do for the (X) symbol. Can we have any custom accessory for this or else how to achieve this?

My code:

```
#pragma mark - Table View Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return  1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    optionsLabelArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Yes", @"No", nil];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CheckerCell";
    CustomCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.optionLabel.text = [optionsLabelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.optionLabelSubtitle.text = [optionsLabelSubtitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:78/255.0 green:157/255.0 blue:19/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:167/255.0 green:19/255.0 blue:43/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    }
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView ==_optionsTableView1) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        previousSelectedCell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        previousSelectedCell1 = cell;
        NSLog(@"Row : %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            self.weatherSafeToPlay = YES;
        }
        else
        {
           // MatchDayDataController *sharedController = [MatchDayDataController sharedDataController];
           // sharedController.actions = [sharedController.actions stringByAppendingString:@"Check Weather. "];
            //[sharedController.actions appendString:@"Check Weather. "];

            self.weatherSafeToPlay = NO;
        }
        NSLog(@"Is Weather safe: %hhd", self.weatherSafeToPlay);
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: tableViewCell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DisclosureViewX"]];

Comment: Dinesh..your suggestion works fine but i have two rows and now i am setting two images yes(tick) & no(X). Both of them are appearing together but only one should be displayed at a time. any idea how to hide to bring only one at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign your own image to accessoryView of table cell. Create an image of (X) symbol and use that image as accessoryView.

```
cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your X Image"]];
```

Comment: your suggestion works fine but i have two rows and now i am setting two images yes(tick) & no(X). Both of them are appearing together but only one should be displayed at a time. any idea how to hide to bring only one at a time?

Comment: if(index path.row == 0) { cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;} else { cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your X Image"]];}

Comment: Will this works? or you first want to show (yes) and then (x) for the same row?

Comment: spaleja there are two rows .. by default nothing should be displayed. when i click on row2 should show X and click on row1 a tick but not both at the same time.

Comment: -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];   if(index path.row == 0) { cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;} else { cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your X Image"]];}}

Comment: spaleja ..  but if i click on both rows both are visible at the same time.. which is not require. only one should be displayed. my code goes like this..if(index path.row == 0) { cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your tick Image"]} else { cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your X Image"]]

Comment: @Lalit_vicky: append this code after the **if-else** condition in the **-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** `[self.tableView beginUpdates]; [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row%1 inSection:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; [self.tableView endUpdates];`

Comment: @Lalit_vicky: also, just a heads up (if you're going down this path for real), it seems you aren't using any logic to remember the selected row, in which case, when you have many rows and you scroll these rows out of view and upon returning to these cells, the cell will reload to original state and will not have the tick nor the cross on it. To handle this, you'll need to make changes in the -cellForRowAtIndexPath to somehow retrieve the selection state of the rows.

Comment: @staticVoidMan thanks for the suggestion. I tried adding the mentioned code. Now when i click on the row it appears and just fades away. My aim is to make only one(either tick(first row) or cross (Second row)) symbol to be visible at a time. It looks i am very close .

Comment: _sorry, modulus operation was incorrect_. try this: `if(indexPath.row == 0) { cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Your tick Image"]]; [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; } else { cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Your X Image"]]; [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];}`

Comment: @Lalit_vicky: yes it should work because when you call methods like `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:`, `-reloadSections:` or `-reloadData`, it basically refreshes the cells by calling all the required `UITableView` datasource methods again out of which, remember that the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is the key datasource method here.

Answer (score 2):

not heard of any accessory type for cross but in such cases, i simply use unicode characters.
It's lighter than using an image and is a simple matter of just changing the text.

- @"\u2713" for ✓
- @"\u2717" for ✗

You can:

1. Create a custom UITableViewCell having a 32by32 (or any dimension) UILabel (on the right/left/middle/wherever)
2. in -didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you can change the text of this UILabel
3. @"\u2713" for checkmark or @"\u2717" for crossmark

A simple example (on the default UITableViewCell's default textLabel, just for the idea):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"\u2713"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"\u2717";
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"\u2713";
    }
}
```

---

**OR...** when not using a custom cell, something like:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //set your text to cell.textLabel.text

    //create your own UILabel
    UILabel *lblAcc = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
    [lblAcc setTag:100];
    [lblAcc setText:@"?"];
    [lblAcc setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [lblAcc setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

    //set as custom AccessoryView on cell
    [cell setAccessoryView:lblAcc];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *strAccessory = [(UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:100] text];

    //the -isEqualToString is a bit heavier than checking a simple bool or int value
    //so since you should be remembering the selected cells anyways, you can change
    //the if-logic to compare with a bool rather than the string comparison.
    //but for now, we'll do:
    if([strAccessory isEqualToString:@"\u2713"]) {
        [(UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:100] setText:@"\u2717"];
    }
    else {
        [(UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:100] setText:@"\u2713"];
    }
}
```

---

for more unicode characters... this link:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/List_of_useful_symbols